# Почему набор бит, хранящийся в памяти, вещественного числа не совпадает с набором бит, если переводит вручную

Tags: c++, числа

Я написла такой код для проверки себя

```
#include <iostream>
#include <format>
#include <string>

int main() {
    union {
        unsigned int i;
        float data = 0.6;
    };

    std::string answer = std::format("{:032b}", i);
    std::cout << answer.substr(0, 8) + " " + answer.substr(8, 8) + " " + answer.substr(16, 8) + " " + answer.substr(24, 8);
}
```

И вот что получается

| Число | Вручную | Код | Число из набора бит(вручную и код) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.6 | 00111111 00011001 10011001 10011001 | 00111111 00011001 10011001 10011010 | 1058642329 1058642330 |
| 0.1366 | 00111110 00001011 11100000 11011110 | 00111110 00001011 11100000 11011111 | 1040965854 1040965855 |
| 0.402 | 00111110 11001101 11010010 11110001 | 00111110 11001101 11010010 11110010 | 1053676273 1053676274 |

Я сначала решил, что где-то вру, но каждый раз врать на еденицу меньше трудно

Comment: Почему то таблица не отображается нормально

Comment: Что такое «вручную»?

Comment: Это как в вузе учили

Comment: А как в вузе учили?

Comment: Переводим число в двоичный код
Считаем смещенный порядок(на сколько надо сдвинуть запятую) + 127
После записываем 23 знака мантисы(при необходимости добавляем нули)

Ну и первый бит знак

Comment: Вот ссылка: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zB2TWLz3Ml9_auledhWQKbGgE8Vy-c1H/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Может, это банальное округление двоичной записи числа?

Comment: Возможно и так я не знаю. Просто препод дал эти три числа и все три числа не совпали

Comment: А посмотрите на мантиссу в double для тех же чисел

Comment: C double первые два числа совпали, а последнее нет. (4600913408118717677 и 4600913408118717678)

Моя мантисса: 1001 10111010 01011110 00110101 00111111 01111100 11101101
Мантисса код: 1001 10111010 01011110 00110101 00111111 01111100 11101110

Это для последнего, потому что для других совпала

Comment: Похоже, что при преобразовании вручную, младшие разряды, не помещающиеся в мантиссу вы просто отбрасываете, хотя нужно округлять к ближайшему ([Round to nearest, ties to even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Roundings_to_nearest)). Небольшой [пример](https://godbolt.org/z/PrWGzosfd), который, надеюсь, поможет лучше понять суть проблемы.

Comment: Всё спасибо я понял, посмотрев ваш пример